# Duda listas/arrays

Tags: javascript, array, lista

**Enunciado:**  En este ejercicio tienes que rellenar un array con los números del 10 al 20 y mostrarlo por consola.

¿Sería algo así?:

```
const array= [ 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 ];
console.log(array);
```

Dudo que sea esto, ya que simplemente he creado un array "a mano", pero es que en el enunciado no indica que lo tuviera que hacer de manera automática.

Comment: Lo lógico será que generes el array mediante Javascript, puedes intentar algo de código para generarlo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supongo que tu tarea es respecto a JavaScript, aunque no lo incluiste en la etiqueta.

Podría ser algo así:

```
var array = [];
for(var i = 10; i <= 20; i++)
    array.push(i);
console.log(array);
```